# How can I make a NSTableCellView editable after a doubleclick?

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, nstextfield

**SETUP:**

I created a `NSTableView`, which has a normal `NSTableCellView`, in Storyboard. Now I click on the textfield within the NSTableCellView and select `Editable` as Behavior. Build & Launch.

**RESULT:**

When you click on a cell, it becomes highlighted, if you then click on it again it will become editable. You would assume that if you double clicked (first highlight, then edit) another cell that would go straight into editing mode, but this is not the case it will only highlight it. Then I have to wait a short amount before I can click to edit.

**PREFERRED RESULT:**

When I edit a cell and double click on another cell it should go straight into editing mode.

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.tableView setDoubleAction:@selector(doubleClick:)]; 
//...
- (void)doubleClick:(id)sender
{
   //set your cell to editable mode
}
```

Comment: How do you set the cell to editable mode? Could you enhance your answer?

Comment: When I set the doubleAction property other then nil the cell become editable when I click on it, but it should just select at that point